# Are there any plans for PHP to populate $_FILES when handling PUT requests?

Tags: php, put, multipart

I understand that multipart requests (usually including file uploads) require a **POST** HTTP verb because that's the only verb that PHP will work with ***$_FILES*** but this is not ideal when working with REST APIs.

Are there any plans for PHP to support **PUT**, **PATCH** with multipart requests in the near future or this is definitely an impossibility?

Comment: We can't answer that. If it's not part of any published roadmap you would need to ask the maintainers of PHP. https://www.php.net/support

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because we can't answer questions about the internal PHP roadmap